# Creating censored DV for survival analysis (in long form)

Tags: r

Another R newbie question.

I am working on a project that requires me to use survival analysis.  Specifically, I need to use discrete-unit survival analysis (so Cox regression or other methods that assume my DV is continuous are out of the question).

I have transformed my dataset into long form, and I need to create a censored DV ("dv") by (STEP 1) finding the last time a variable ("q") =1; (STEP 2) recoding my "dv" as "0" at time+1; (STEP 3) recoding my "dv" as "NA" at time+2...n; (STEP 4) deleting all of the observations (rows) for when "dv"=NA.

Before I do this, it seems like I should create to be that I should create a DV that is assigned to "1" by default.  My data would look like this after step 3:

```
 id  time q  dv   
 1    1   1   1
 1    2   0   1
 1    3   1   1
 1    4   0   0
 1    5   0   NA
 1    6   0   NA
 2    1   1   1
 2    2   1   1
 2    3   0   0
 2    4   0   NA
 2    5   0   NA
 2    6   0   NA
```

Please note that "q" can vary between "0" or "1" over time (See the observation for id=1 at time=2), but due to the nature of survival analysis, "dv" cannot.  What I need to do is create a variable that finds the LAST time that "q" changes between "1" and "0", and then is censored accordingly.  After Step 4, my data should look like this:

```
 id  time q  dv   
 1    1   1   1
 1    2   0   1
 1    3   1   1
 1    4   0   0
 2    1   1   1
 2    2   1   1
 2    3   0   0
```

Thanks for any and all help possible!

Comment: Assuming `dv` is you event occurrence in a DTSA, are you sure the outlined steps are the most practical approach? How does the original (wide) data look like?

Comment: While I'm no expert, from the reading that I've done I think that they are.  Each question also has time-varying attributes which will be used as predictors in the model, and as they change from time to time so long form is neccessary.

Comment: Long format is what you want for your survival model, not necessary for your recording work... I took a shot at it however, see below.

Answer (score 0):

This got more verbose than intended, but it does the job for you long-format snippet:

I start from the provided data, but use wide instead of long.

```
zz <- textConnection("id  time q  dv   
1    1   1   1
1    2   0   1
1    3   1   1
1    4   0   0
1    5   0   NA
1    6   0   NA
2    1   1   1
2    2   1   1
2    3   0   0
2    4   0   NA
2    5   0   NA
2    6   0   NA
")
d <- read.table(zz, header = TRUE)
d$dv <- NULL
close(zz)

# start out with wide instead of long
dw <- reshape(d, direction='wide', timevar="time", sep="") 
dw
```

```
##   id q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6
## 1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
## 7  2  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

Use a function that generates the proper “dv” variable per wide row/observation.

```
censor <- function(periods) {
  n <- length(periods)
  cperiods <- periods*1:n # multiply to get positions
  n.obs <- max(cperiods) # position of last q=1, and one q=0  
  periods[(n.obs+1):n] <- NA # NA's for periods outside observed range
  n.cens <- n - n.obs - 1 # number censored
  c(rep(1, n.obs-1), 0, rep(NA, n.cens+1)) # fill "dv" accordingly
}
```

Apply said function, resulting in a properly censored wide dataset.

```
# apply censored(), create dv variable in wide format
dw.censored <- data.frame(t(apply(dw, 1, FUN = censor)))
dw.censored
```

```
##   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
## 1  1  1  1  0 NA NA NA
## 7  1  1  0 NA NA NA NA
```

Now back to a long format (with aesthetic formating, ordering, etc.)

```
dl.censored <- reshape(dw.censored, varying = 1:7, timevar = "time", 
                       sep = "", direction = "long")
dl.censored <- dl.censored[order(dl.censored$id, dl.censored$time),]
dl.censored$dv <- dl.censored$X
rownames(dl.censored) <- dl.censored$X <- NULL
dl.censored

##    time id dv
## 1     1  1  1
## 2     2  1  1
## 3     3  1  1
## 4     4  1  0
## 5     5  1 NA
## 6     6  1 NA
## 7     7  1 NA
## 8     1  2  1
## 9     2  2  1
## 10    3  2  0
## 11    4  2 NA
## 12    5  2 NA
## 13    6  2 NA
## 14    7  2 NA
```

And without the NA's:

```
dl.censored <- na.omit(dl.censored)  # without NA's
dl.censored
```

```
##    time id dv
## 1     1  1  1
## 2     2  1  1
## 3     3  1  1
## 4     4  1  0
## 8     1  2  1
## 9     2  2  1
## 10    3  2  0
```